# nodejs Can't resolve 'child_process'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

i try to use the nodejs node-adodb module in combination with react, but i keep getting the error:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process'

i tried to google sollutions but both of these wont work, i tried adding:

```
"browser":{ "child_process": false }
```

to my package.json, didnt solve it and i tried adding:

```
node: { child_process: "empty" // fs: "empty", // if unable to resolve "fs" },
```

to my webpack.config.js, also didnt solve this issue.

any other things i can try ?

if i use the module without react it works fine

Comment: Anybody got a clue ?